# Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox with dynamic ItemSource problem

Tags: c#, telerik

I have an RadAutoCompleteBox with a dynamic ItemSource that works some places and not others.  In the setter for the SearchText I run a search and populate the ItemSource.  In the box I'm working on now, the ItemSource's ObservableCollection is giving me "Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Core.dll" when i try and add item to it. This method works many places elsewhere, and If i manually set the SearchText elsewhere the offending code runs without error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the XAML:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox 
    Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"
    x:Name="AutoCompleteBoxMakeModel"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MakeModelCollection}"
    SearchText="{Binding MakeModelTerm, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMakeModel, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    TextSearchPath="Display"
    TextSearchMode="Contains"
    AutoCompleteMode="Suggest"
    IsDropDownOpen="{Binding IsMakeModelDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
    DropDownItemTemplate="{StaticResource MakeModelSearchTemplate}"
    DropDownWidth="300"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275"  Height="25" Margin="0,3,0,0" >
    <telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
        <telerik:VisualStudio2013Theme/>
    </telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

And here's the offending code:

```
private string makeModelTerm;
public string MakeModelTerm
{
    get { return makeModelTerm; }
    set
    {
        if (makeModelTerm == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        makeModelTerm = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MakeModelTerm");
        if (value.Length > 2)
        {
            SearchMakeModel(value);
        }
    }
}

private void SearchMakeModel(string value)
{
    LookUpRepository er = new LookUpRepository();
    var list = er.SearchMakeModel(value);
    MakeModelCollection.Clear();
    list.ForEach(MakeModelCollection.Add); // This triggers the System.ArgumentException on each value in list
    this.IsMakeModelDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear that what the problem is. Is the control itself not working?

Answer (score 1):

The TextSearchPath didn't match the model.

Typos sukc

Answer (score 1):

You should pass delegate to list.ForEach as below.

```
list.ForEach(item => MakeModelCollection.Add(item));
```

For your reference, please look at microsoft implementaion here for the same :

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,0e5a9cf0a310b9e5

Comment: This wasn't the solution. There was a problem with the control setup

Comment: It makes no difference if you pass an anonymous function or a method group as an argument.